# Refer particular value in `dplyr::mutate()`

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(quantmod)

# inflation data
getSymbols("CPIAUCSL", src='FRED')
avg.cpi <- apply.yearly(CPIAUCSL, mean)
cf <- avg.cpi/as.numeric(avg.cpi['1991']) # using 1991 as the base year
cf <- as.data.frame(cf)
cf$year <- rownames(cf)
cf <- tail(cf, 25)
rownames(cf) <- NULL
cf$year <- lapply(cf$year, function(x) as.numeric(head(unlist(strsplit(x, "-")), 1)))
rm(CPIAUCSL)
# end of inflation data get

tmp <- data.frame(year=c(rep(1991,2), rep(1992,2)), price=c(12.03, 12.98, 14.05, 14.58))
tmp %>% mutate(infl.price = price / cf[cf$year == year, ]$CPIAUCSL)
```

I want to get the following result:

```
year price
1991 12.03
1991 12.98
1992 13.64
1992 14.16
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
Warning message:
In cf$year == tmp$year :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

And with `%in%` it produces and incorrect result.

Comment: Wondering if you are looking for `%in%` instead of `==` (haven't tested)

Comment: Make sure you include all relevant pacakges (`apply.yearly` isn't in base R). Also please share your data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). It's best if we can just copy/paste your code into R to run your code. Ideally include the desired output for the sample input.

Comment: @MrFlick I have updated.

Comment: Your code  `lapply(`  was not necessary and if you check the `str(cf)` `year` is a `list`.  It would have been easier with `cf$year <- year(as.Date(cf$year))`

Comment: @akrun I was wondering why ``cf`` was formatted strangely.  I had to coerce it into numeric before I could ``dplyr::inner_join``

Comment: @divide_by_zero It was because the `lapply` output will be a list and OP assigned the list as a column

Comment: Thanks for pointing out some more improvements!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it might be easier to join the `CPIAUCSL` column in `cf` into `tmp` before you try to mutate:

```
cf$year = as.numeric(cf$year)
tmp = tmp %>% inner_join(cf, by = "year") %>% mutate(infl.price = price / CPIAUCSL)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `cf` structure is a list of lists which is unfriendly. It woud have been nicer to have

```
cf$year <- sapply(cf$year, function(x) as.numeric(head(unlist(strsplit(x, "-")), 1)))
```

which at least returns a simple vector.

Additional, the subsetting operator `[]` is not properly vectorized for this type of operation. The `mutate()` function does not iterate over rows, it operates on entire columns at a time. When you do

```
cf[cf$year == year, ]$CPIAUCSL
```

There is not just one `year` value, `mutate` is trying to do them all at once.

You'd be better off doing a proper merge with your data and then do the mutate. This will basically do the same thing as your pseudo-merge that you were trying to do in your version.

You can do

```
tmp %>% left_join(cf) %>% 
    mutate(infl.price = price / CPIAUCSL) %>% 
    select(-CPIAUCSL)
```

to get

```
  year price infl.price
1 1991 12.03   12.03000
2 1991 12.98   12.98000
3 1992 14.05   13.63527
4 1992 14.58   14.14962
```